# Problems with UPnP Java Libraries

Tags: java, upnp

I'm starting to get crazy reading forums and trying different Java UPnP libraries but not IGDs are found in my net.

First of all I have to remark that UPnP works fine from a program I've made in C++ (using miniupnp) so my router is properlu configured to work with UPnP.

```
Sending M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 2

M-SEARCH Reply:
ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1
Location: http://192.168.25.50:1780/InternetGatewayDevice.xml
...
```

I've tried to develope applications using weupnp (a kind of miniupnp for java), using sbbi upnp lib and Cling upnp, but curiously all three APIs are unable to find response from my router.

Does anybody know if Java upnp APIs have some dependency or requirement I'm missing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't comment on the other libraries but [ohNet](http://www.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) includes working Java bindings.  You'll find documentation links on the project wiki and the source code includes tests which demonstrate how to implement most standard operations.  (I should note that I contribute to this project)

Comment: Just yesterday I finally made Cling work for me. Apparently I was missing teteal-common jar in my project (it's in core library folder).   No other dependencies needed. So the project includes: cling-core-1.0.5.jar, teleal-common-1.0.13.jar and cling-support-1.0.5.jar. I am testing with FreeBSD, linux and Cisco EPC2425 home router.

Comment: weupnp works fine with my freebox (http://portail.free.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

Is that request traces from your Java app or the C++ app? I know that some frameworks scan for devices using ST: upnp:rootdevice which makes some routers only announce themselves, and not any other devices. If you turn OFF upnp in your router it starts to forward them.

But basically that is a broken framework, you should be able to define which ST you are scanning for.

If you can provide network dumps for your Java app as well that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Weupnp 0.1.2 can now focus on specific ST and filter replies according to that.

As jishi says, lots of potential problems came from `upnp:rootdevice` messages.

If you still have need for this, may I suggest you to try the [latest version of weupnp](http://bitletorg.github.io/weupnp/)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the EPC2425 could also be a problem, it's know to eat SSDP packets: https://sonos.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42/~/network-hardware-compatibility